# MySql: Group By with sorting

Tags: mysql, group-by, columnsorting

i've got some trouble in group by

Table VS Wanted Result

```
//table
ID  | Quantity | Price
----+----------+---------
1902|    2     |  100
1915|    1     |  20
2010|    2     |  30
2052|    3     |  20

//Wanted result
ID  | Quantity | Price
----+----------+---------
1900|    3     |  120
2000|    5     |  50
```

Help me to solve this.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With making lots of assumptions and purely looking at your current table and desired results, here is something that should work for you (note, change `table` with your actual table name).

```
SELECT group_by_id, 
       Sum(quantity), 
       Sum(price) 
FROM   (SELECT LEFT(id, 2) AS group_by_id, 
               quantity, 
               price 
        FROM   table) AS tdata 
GROUP  BY group_by_id
```

Basically, we use a sub-query to get the first 2 characters of each id column and then group by this column in the outer query to calculate our quantity and price.

Answer (score 0):

You should have one table to store their relationship or have one field for store foreign key.

Example:

```
//table
ID  | Quantity | Price  | ParentID
----+----------+---------------------
1902|    2     |  100   | 1900
1915|    1     |  20    | 1900
2010|    2     |  30    | 2000
2052|    3     |  20    | 2000
```

MySQL

```
SELECT ParentID,SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity,SUM(Price) AS TotalPrice FROM TableName GROUP BY ParentID
```